# Dropzone upload size limit to 256MB even set to 2000MB

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, production-environment

Got this weir problem try to solve it with no luck for days. Hope anyone here can help. 
The code working fine at the local machine but production on ruby, the upload file size limited to 256MB, the upload window closes itself with no error messages

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'audio_files.js' %>

 <script>
  $(function() {
      Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

      var mediaDropzone= new Dropzone("#media-dropzone",
          {maxFilesize: 2000,
              paramName: "audio_file[file]",
              maxFiles:1,
              timeout:0 ,

              init: function() {
                  this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                      alert("No more files please!");
                  });
              },
              complete: function (file) {
                  if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                      //once all the files have been uploaded - close window and refresh page.
                      //close modal and refresh page.
                      //alert("MADE IT HERE");
                      $('#download').modal('hide');
                      location.reload();
                  }
                  }

          });// max file size is 256MB // set param of uploaded file.)


     /* $("#media-dropzone").dropzone({
          paramName: "audio_file[file]"
      });*/

      //return mediaDropzone.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
          //var imageUrl;
          //imageUrl = responseText.file_name.url;
     // });
      Dropzone.options.mediaDropzone= {
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }

      }
  });
```

Comment: Options: it could be a setting in your hosting apache/nginx environment as well? Did you rebuild the assets upon deploy?

Comment: No, I suppose I didn't. I am not sure how to do that. How do I check the setting?

Comment: You didn't rebuild the assets? You should be able to inspect with your browser if the used/downloaded javascript includes your code. Or asking for the setting? Which server are you using? Apache or nginx?

Comment: Check this https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/11/admin_manual/configuration_files/big_file_upload_configuration.html?highlight=big%20file%20upload

Comment: I think it is nginx. but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I can see from inspect that all codes are up to date.

Comment: At what filesize do you get the error? In nginx the setting you would be looking for is `client_max_body_size` and it would result in a `413 (Request Entity Too Large)` error (in your browser check/inspect the network traffic if the upload is started and an error is returned).

Comment: I didn't get any error, only when I upload large file around 900mb the upload window close itself after few minutes during uploading. like it hit some kind of limit. the file did not get through to the server. How do I open the Nginx config? I am try to find that client max body size

Comment: You should get an error in the browser. In the developer tools there should be a network tab. It is impossible for me to answer where you would find the `nginx.conf` file without knowing _anything_ about your deployment server. Do you use any kind of hosting? If your servers are self-managed, ask whoever set it up. By default, the configuration file is named `nginx.conf` and placed in the directory `/usr/local/nginx/conf` , `/etc/nginx` , or `/usr/local/etc/nginx` , but this could vary greatly depending on actual implementation.

Comment: I find it and changed the client max body size from 200M to 2000M now, for this to work am I reproduce the website just rails s  -e ? or is there a commend for Nginx to rebuilt? thanks

Comment: after reproduce. it still the same problem

Comment: You have to stop and start nginx for the configuration to have effect.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem. really appreciated !! It took few programmers and no one thinks of this!!

Comment: @KCChen How do you fixed this issue, I have the same problem, I increased client_max_body_size=500M but it is still blocking the large files for dropzone

Comment: @fredyK It was nginx problem look for that file limit and change it fix my problem.